# Is there any way to walk on PC?

Tags: bully

I've just started playing Bully: Scholarship Edition on Steam. It says at the start of the game that you can change your movement speed with an analog input method, but I don't have a controller so I'm using KB+M. Jimmy seems to run at full speed all the time when I press "W". Is there any way to walk instead of run?

Comment: Shift doesn't do anything like in all the others games ?